# Remove Documents,Downloads,Music directories from home directory

Tags: macbook-pro

How to remove those directories **permanently**? Not just to hide them, but delete. Every time system reboots they are recreated and I have to `sudo rm -rf NastyDir*`.
Is there anything I can change in system settings?

Comment: I do not believe there is any way to permanently delete these folders; they are a basic part of the user's $HOME profile structure. Why would you want to delete them anyway?

Comment: Why would I need such directories in $HOME? I don`t think that it is worth having Downloads dir as after I download I either delete file or archive it somewhere else. And who keeps Music in their $HOME?

Comment: OS X is a modern UNIX system. As such, it is a multi-user system that is designed to isolate each user's data to protect the user's privacy and security. While it is possible to share data via the public folders, all the contents of the user's home directory are protected. This is by design and is a security paradigm that is shared by all modern, multi-user operating systems.

Comment: P.S. - I keep EVERYTHING in $HOME. My MacBook travels with me everywhere. It makes zero sense to me to segregate my data stores. Different strokes. :)

Comment: Just to understand the purpose: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Ceesaxp, I use my mac for work (no movies, no music, no documents). Just ssh to remote server and that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has worked for me so far under Snow Leopard, I’m currently away from home and won’t be able to test this on Yostemite for quite a while:

```
mkdir foo
sudo mv NastyDir foo/NastyDir
sudo ln -s foo/NastyDir .
```

Now reboot and log in.

```
sudo rm -rf NastyDir foo/NastyDir
```

Reboot, log in, and find that there are no `NastyDir`s to be found.

Answer (score 5):

Trane is right. Love 'em or 'hate 'em the system will always recreate them when you delete them.

You might try hiding them like this using Terminal

```
chflags hidden ~/Documents/
```

That will hide (for example) the documents folder in your home directory.

Not sure if O/S X will then un-hide it for you but it might be worth a try...

Comment: Looks like the folders are like marmite! You either Love it or hate it like you say. In this case @Bgibas hates the folders but OS X loves them! (Sorry, just had to say this. :) )

Comment: The OP wants to delete them, not hide them. This doesn’t answer the Q. -1

Comment: You. can also do. `chflags nohidden ~/Documents/` to unhide